# Connect from Hive to HDFS (JSON Files)

Tags: java, json, hadoop, twitter, hive

I have already built up a hadoop cluster with apache flume to import twitter data, it works fine.

Now I wanna start analytics with apache hive on the twitter data. On the web I found following example from cloudera.

https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

But now, by creating the table, hive returns the following error message:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: text:STRING, Query returned non-zero code: 1, 
cause: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: text:STRING,
```

On web i didn't found something about this (only by starting hive), maybe someone here can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows or Linux ? I never got anything related to Hadoop to work on Windows, with similar exceptions if I recall correctly, and in the end I just installed a Fedora VM. Smooth sailing from then on.

Comment: Im doing that on ubuntu. maybe the full command for creating the table would help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first problem are solved by myself. forgot a semicolon on the command. sorry for this.

But now I get another error message after start jobs over hive. All Query Jobs on Hive abort after some seconds. In the Log I found only this:

```
2015-03-25 14:47:40,680 ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Container complete event for unknown container id container_1427105751169_0006_01_000030
```

Any Ideas here?